# Fastest way to combine thousands of arrays uniquely in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am getting data from a database. Each result looks something like this

```
ASDF-1234-JKL-F1-STUFF
```

There are 50,000 results. Each one is being exploded

```
$exploded = explode('-',$dash_delimited_datum);

// $exploded = array('ASDF','1234','JKL','F1','STUFF');
```

I tried this:

```
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    $data = array_merge($data,explode('-',$row[0]));
}
```

But I hit the server timeout of 5 minutes with it.

And this didn't work at all:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    $data_parts = explode('-',$row[0]);
    foreach($data_parts as $value) {
        $data = array_push(($data,$value);
    }
}
```

Unexpectedly, this worked, taking "only" 9 seconds, but I wonder if I can make it even faster:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    $data = array_unique(array_merge($data,explode('-',$row[0])));
}
```

EDIT: I came up with an solution that I thought would be the best one, at 800ms
Note that I used a "closure" (the anonymous function) to remove numeric keys and I assumed it was a drag on speed. But actually, removing it caused the script to timeout at 30s.

```
$data=array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    $data_parts = array_flip(array_filter(explode('-',$row[0]),
    function($value) {
        if(is_numeric($value)) {
                return false;
        } else return true;
    }));

    $data = array_merge($data,$data_parts);
}
$data = array_keys($data);
sort($data);
```

Conclusions:

Every fast answer used tricks involving the array keys, rather than values. And the difference between my best answer and the two very fast answers below seems to be their use of `foreach` inside the `while loop` to assign values directly to the main `$data` array. PHP **function calls are supposedly expensive**, and this example seems to prove that **they really are**. Both of the best answers gave me results in under 300 milliseconds. My best answer only worked fast when I filtered out numeric values, otherwise it ran into 30 second server timeout.

So, I guess if you are processing massive amounts of data, use *constructs* and *not functions* whenever you can.

Note about the (yes I know they're deprecated) mysql functions
One answer suggested that I use `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. Actually, `mysql_fetch_row` is supposed to be "fastest", but the change made absolutely no difference in the speed of page loading with this data set (about 48,000 results). I also tried using `mysql_result`. The PHP docs say that it's slower when retrieving multiple rows, and it is a lot slower.

This took 6.27 seconds to load, versus about 0.27 seconds (270 milliseconds) for the similarly structured best answer.

```
$i=0;
while($data_parts = explode('-',mysql_result($result,$i,0)) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    foreach($data_parts as $value) {
        $data[$value] = 1;
    }
}
$data = array_keys($data);
```

Comment: Try using `mysql_fetch_assoc` instead of `mysql_fetch_array`. mysql_fetch_array returns both numeric and associative indexes (effectively doubling the size of your array). In addition, try to use a little functions as possible within your `while` loop. For instance, if you iterate through 50,000 elements, and have 3 function calls in each iteration, thats 150,000 times the functions are called.

Comment: You'd be able to speed it up a little bit by moving `array_unique` to outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this (I removed your counter, but you can add back in if its necessary):

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) )
{
    $data_parts = explode('-',$row[0]);

    foreach($data_parts as $value)
    {
        if (!isset($data[$value]))
            $data[$value] = $i++;
    }
}

$data = array_flip($data);
```

I can't really benchmark on my computer, so if its slower than your implementations, let me know!

Comment: I just came up with a solution that was delivered to my browser in 890ms. I was extremely surprised to see your solution is even faster, at about 300ms! It's strange how much work we need to put in to make PHP process arrays efficiently.

Comment: With your method, the DOM gets loaded in 255 - 265 milliseconds. Interestingly, when I added `$j += count($data_parts)` to see how many array elements were process, it added about 15ms. When an `&& is_numeric($value)` check to your if statement (because I am actually only interested in the string values), it also added about 15ms. I guess that demonstrates the cost of function calls.

Comment: I also tried removing your `if(!isset($data[$value]))` statement. I didn't see the point in it, since the keys must be unique anyway. But removing it made very little difference, and may have even added 5-10ms. I also would use `$data = array_keys($data)` at the end, rather than `$data = array_flip($data)`, but result time was not affected by it.

Comment: @ButtleButkus The reason for the `isset`, is that without it, the flipped array won't have sequential indexes. Take this example: `A-B-B-C`, without the isset, the final array will be `[0=>A, 2=>B, 3=>C]` (note no value @ index 1). Where as with the isset, you will get the expected output of `[0=>A, 1=>B, 2=>C]`. But if you were to use `array_keys`, it is unnecessary (I actually didn't even know that function existed).

Comment: I realized you were using it to keep the keys in order. I just didn't see the point of using it when `array_keys` is available. But, strangely, there's not much difference in speed either way.

Answer (score 2):

In order to speed the process, instead of using expensive functions to deal with arrays, using an associative array (*hash*) to ensure unique values should have the whole faster

```
$i = 0;
$hash = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }
    foreach (explode('-', $row[0]) as $s) {
        $hash[ $s ] = 1;
    }
}
```

This way, all strings are *uniquely* stored in an associative array (called *hash*).

The resulting array is `$hash` keys ( `$data` )

```
$data = array_keys( $hash );
print_r( $data );
```

Comment: All php arrays are associative.

Comment: I mean... use it in an associative way, like in Perl. Instead of using the indexed array - which are associative anyway but this is not the point - we want to use the benefit of the array keys which are unique, and accessed quickly.

Comment: Your answer result in DOM load within 270 ms. Very good. And that is parsing 48,000 results, which when exploded is processing 240,991 array elements. AND this is running on a virtual machine on my desktop computer!

Answer (score 0):

Try using mysql_fetch_assoc instead of mysql_fetch_array. mysql_fetch_array returns both numeric and associative indexes (effectively doubling the size of your array). In addition, try to use a little functions as possible within your while loop. For instance, if you iterate through 50,000 elements, and have 3 function calls in each iteration, thats 150,000 times the functions are called.

In addition, why not strip duplicates before even passing the result to the loop?

```
SELECT someField 
FROM someTable 
GROUP BY someField 
HAVING COUNT(someField)>0
```

Once running that, run your loop

```
$data = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
    $i++;
    if($i > 99999) {
        break;
    }

    $data[] = explode('-',$row[0]);
}
```

Comment: You make one good point, about mysql_fetch_array being slower than mysql_fetch_assoc. But actually, since I'm getting a single column I might as well use mysql_fetch_row, which returns "fast" numeric keys. The funny thing is that using any of those didn't make the slightest difference to my script's speed. I will add some more notes about this in my question. Also, I believe your loop is faulty because each `explode` will add an array as an element, creating a multi-dim array. Also, your query suggestion doesn't work. The data IS unique, but not once I explode it on '-'.