# Is my preg_match, or get_file_contents slowing my page?

Tags: php, regex

my website currently uses a template system, which loads a list of `.tpl` files and replaces `{bracelet}` with the correct content and outputs this on the page.

I need to get a list of all bracelets within all the templates so I can stop the PHP from running code specific for a bracelet, this will help reduce the amount of queries.

Currently my page loads in 1.09 seconds, if I add the below code then the page load time goes up to 1.53 seconds.

I gather this is due to me loading possibly 100 or so files into memory, and then to a `preg_match_all` and pushing them all into one array?

```
bracelets = [];

foreach($files as $file) {

    if (empty($file)) continue;

    $html = get_file_contents($file);


    $matches = [];

    preg_match_all("/{(.*?)\}/", $html, $matches);


    bracelets = (array_merge($bracelets, $matches[1]));
}

bracelets = array_unique(bracelets);
```

What is the bit of code causing the speed decrease?

Comment: What about `"/{([^{}]+)}/"`??

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew not sure how the regex will change the speed? It's still an regex?

Comment: PCRE performance usually degrades when lazy dot pattern has to match huge chunks of data. And negated character classes with a greedy `+` do not suffer from this problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah gotcha, doesn't seem to be making much of a speed increase but now JavaScript is being returned, there a way to ignore a match if it contains white space?

Comment: @MartynBall add \s before the closing ] bracket.

Comment: Aha, so you want to only match `{bracelet}` and not return `{brace let}`? Use `"/{([^{}\s]+)}/"`

Comment: Also how many files are you iterating here? Do you need to do that in every request, can't you cache those? I guess template files won't change between requests. Why don't you compile them into a format which does not require parsing?

Comment: The regex change made the load time 1.41 seconds. Currently iterating over 252 files, and yeah I could cache the array of bracelets which will speed it up, however still want to get it as quick as possible.

Comment: See [Fastest way to combine thousands of arrays uniquely in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807922/fastest-way-to-combine-thousands-of-arrays-uniquely-in-php).

Comment: Both preg-match and file-get-contents can be expensive (The former because it's doing a lot of string analysis with a potentially complicated pattern on a potentially long string, the latter because it requires hitting the filesystem and file IO is always orders of magnitudes slower than memory operations).  So yeah, it's a fair bet that this code is going to be slow with a lot of files and long strings.  Did you try benchmarking it to determine exactly how slow?  This can be as simple as recording microtime() at the start and end of the code, or using something like the XDebug profiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with files of unknown length lazy dot based patterns may degrade performance. It happens in case of large chunks of text appearing between the delimiters, here, braces, since the `{.*?}` works like this: `{` is matched, then `.*?` is skipped and `}` is searched for. If it is not there, `.*?` is used to match the char after `{` and the next char is tested for `}`. This processes repeats as many times as there are chars other than `}` before `}` is found. It means the engine still spends too much time on getting to the closing delimiter.

When using a `[^}]` negated character class, you may use a greedy `*` or `+`quantifier  since you no longer need to test all chars separately, the engine greedily grabs all 1/0 or more chars other than `}` at once and comes up to `}` (if there is any).\

Since you need to match values like `{bracelet}` and avoid returning `{brace let}` like entries, your current regex is not only slow, it is just wrong.

Replace it with

```
"/{([^{}\s]+)}/"
```

The `[^{}\s]+` part matches 1 or more chars other than `{`, `}` and whitespace.

As for concatenating arrays keeping unique only values, see [Fastest way to combine thousands of arrays uniquely in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16807922/fastest-way-to-combine-thousands-of-arrays-uniquely-in-php).

Comment: Thanks for the help, going to go with a different way to disable code but this was helpful.